# How to write a testing in udf fro a type of array[struct[a:string, b:map[string,string]]]?

Tags: hive, hql, bigdata

How to write a testing in udf for a type of array[struct[a:string, b:map[string,string]]]?The input include a string  and a array[struct[a:string, b:map[string,string]]] type. My code is as fllows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ListObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.MapObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StructObjectInspector;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.StringObjectInspector;

public class UDFClkNum extends GenericUDF {

    private ListObjectInspector listOI;
    private StructObjectInspector structOI;
    private MapObjectInspector mapOI;
    private StringObjectInspector typeOI;

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(DeferredObject[] arg0) throws HiveException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int count = 0;
        List list = listOI.getList(arg0[1].get());
        String type = typeOI.getPrimitiveJavaObject(arg0[0]);
        Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(".*_" + type + "$");
        if (null == list)
            return 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
            Map map = (Map) structOI.getStructFieldData(listOI.getListElement(arg0[1], i), structOI.getStructFieldRef("action_attribute"));
            if (null == map)
                return 0;
            else {
                Matcher m1  = p1.matcher((String)map.get("action_attribute"));
                if (m1.find())
                    ++count;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public String getDisplayString(String[] arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectInspector initialize(ObjectInspector[] arg0)
            throws UDFArgumentException {
        if (2 != arg0.length) {
            throw new UDFArgumentException("arg0 only takes 2 argument");
        }
        ObjectInspector a = arg0[0];
        ObjectInspector b = arg0[1];
        if (!(a instanceof StringObjectInspector)) {
            throw new UDFArgumentException("the argument must be a String");
        }
        if (!(b instanceof ListObjectInspector)) {
            throw new UDFArgumentException("the argument must be an array / list");
        }
        this.typeOI = (StringObjectInspector) a;
        this.listOI = (ListObjectInspector) b;
        if(!(listOI.getListElementObjectInspector() instanceof StructObjectInspector)) {
            throw new UDFArgumentException("the argument must be a list of struct");
        }
        this.structOI = (StructObjectInspector) listOI.getListElementObjectInspector();
        MapObjectInspector mapOI = (MapObjectInspector) structOI.getStructFieldRef("action_attribute");
        return PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaIntObjectInspector;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws HiveException {
        UDFClkNum clk = new UDFClkNum();
        ObjectInspector stringOI = PrimitiveObjectInspectorFactory.javaStringObjectInspector;
        List<String> structFieldNames = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<ObjectInspector> structFieldObjectInspectors = new ArrayList<ObjectInspector>();
        structFieldNames.add("action_attribute");
        structFieldObjectInspectors.add(ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardMapObjectInspector(stringOI, stringOI));
        ObjectInspector structOI = ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardStructObjectInspector(structFieldNames, structFieldObjectInspectors);
        ObjectInspector listOI = ObjectInspectorFactory.getStandardListObjectInspector(structOI);
        DeferredObject[] objs = new DeferredObject[2];
        objs[0] = new DeferredJavaObject("k1");
        //objs[1] = new DeferredJavaObject();
        Object result = clk.evaluate(objs);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

I have trouble to deal with the`objs[1] = new DeferredJavaObject();`. I don't know how to initial the objs[1].